# Foreach only prints one value from the array when using Ajax and onsubmitForm

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I have a PHP script that calls the Twitter 1.1 API, and returns 50 ID numbers. Then I am using a Foreach argument to print the results individualy on to the page.  I want to store each different ID number inside a button as a hidden value, and then use JQuery Ajax to post that value to a different PHP page for further processing without leaving or refreshing the page of 50 ID numbers.

If I use this Foreach argument, the 50 ID numbers are ALL the first result in the array, rather than being 50 individual ID numbers which is not what I want:

```
foreach ($Results as $arrResult) {
    $IDstring = $arrResult['id_str'];
    print("<form id='RT' onsubmit='return submitForm();'>
               <input type='hidden' name='id' value=$IDstring>
               <input type='submit' value='ReTweet'></form>
    ");
}
```

But, If I remove this section from the Foreach argument, 50 individual ID numbers are printed into into hidden values of the forms:

```
onsubmit='return submitForm();'
```

The problem is my JQuery script is listening for submitForm and without that line above the JQuery will not run. Here is my JQuery script:

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'results.php', data: $('#RT').serialize()});

    return false;
}
</script>
```

I know that removing onsubmit='return submitForm();' gives me 50 unique ID numbers from the Foreach, because this code will print 50 buttons which will each contain individual values. But because there is no JQuery script listening for submitForm I have to add **method='post' action='results.php** in order to POST the value of the button but this means the page results.php loads which is not what I want:

```
foreach ($Results as $arrResult) {
    $IDstring = $arrResult['id_str'];
    print("<form id='form' method='post' action='results.php'>
               <input type='hidden' name='id' value=$IDstring>
               <input type='submit' value='ReTweet'></form>");
}
```

So, I want the foreach to print 50 unique ID numbers, while also letting me use the JQuery Ajax script. I hope this is clear, I don't know how else to describe what I want to do :D

Comment: how many form you got using this ? one only ?? or problem is that you get null for other values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now I understand what you're trying to do. I would do it like this.

PHP:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $arrResult) {
    $tweetId = $arrResult['id_str'];
    print('<button type="button" class="mark-tweet" data-tweet-id="' . $tweetId . '"><br/><br/>');
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

    $('.mark-tweet').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-tweet-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'results.php',
            data: {tweetId : id}
        });
    })
      .done(function() {
          alert('The tweet has been deleted');
       })
      .fail(function() {
          alert('Oops, something went wrong! Please try again.');
      });

});
```

**NOTE**: I am not capitalizing the 'r' in $Results as you did. Only class names should start in capital letters (class as in OOP, not CSS)

Comment: Hi Neil :) I do that exactly like you said when I am deleting Tweets and messages in bulk, but I want to be able to choose which Tweets to ReTweet. So, I can print each tweet as text, and have a button under to then ReTweet it if I want. So having a column lets me specify by clicking on a button, instead of a mass ReTweeting of all the ID numbers.

Comment: I could do it using an invisible iframe that pops up when the button is clicked as well. But I am trying to use the JQuery script.

Comment: Keys to the backend are *always* needed to identify which data you're actually talking about. Without, you can't build a system.

Comment: @KustomJack DON't give up, you're so close! :-) I revised my answer now that I better understand what your requirements are. Please give it a shot. Best of luck!

Comment: Oh Neil, the mark-tweet function works perfectly, and IDs are being sent to results.php and are successfully being POSTed back from there to the API again. THANK YOU SO MUCH :D The .done function isn't running, but I have a working version and will integrate that code as part of my learning process. Also, I've lowered the case of the R in results :) Seriously, thanks to you and @Thomas W now I have a working model and an understanding of why it's working.

Comment: @KustomJack Awesome! If the .done() function isn't firing it probably means that id is undefined within the scope of that closure. Try changing it to .done(function() {
          alert('The tweet has been deleted');
       })

Answer (score 0):

OK, we've got you now. You're on the right track to use an ID, and this is straight-forward.

What you need to render are 50 buttons with `onclick` that will call your `markTweet()` JS function & pass it the ID -- and that can do the AJAX post. No form required.

Alternatively, you can render 50 forms with separate IDs ('form'.$tweetId), each with a hidden input & submit button (or just a `<button>`, since the BUTTON element can have a name & value distinct from its content), and an `onclick` that calls `postTweetForm('form${tweetId})' -- thus passing the ID of the selected form to your JS function.

Really, since you're doing it in JS, keeping the UI simple & letting JS do the work is easiest. Here's an example to get started. PHP:

```
foreach ($Results as $arrResult) {
    $tweetId = $arrResult['id_str'];
    print("<button type='button' onclick='markTweet('".$tweetId."');'><br>\n");
}
```

Javascript:

```
function markTweet (tweetId) {
    $.post({
        url: 'results.php', 
        data: {'tweetId': tweetId}
    );
}
```

You should also put in a `success` handler into your AJAX post.. fade in a little green tick or something so the user knows it's worked, because it doesn't always. (I'll let you play with that.)

Try that.. and keep the question up. It's much improved now & may be able to help someone else.

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I'm very new to coding so it can be hard to know how to be concise for others. I'm re-writing the question and will edit the post.

Comment: I don't know if that makes more sense now. I have to go to bed anyway but thanks for your advice Thomas :)

Comment: So, now I know exactly what you mean. I looked at the page source and 50 unique IDs are there, but the single ID='retweets' rendered 50 times means the JQuery script is treating them all as a single value. It's working as it should, I'm just expecting it do what it can't. I'll delete my questions. I think I just annoying people with my stupidity anyway.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you so much for the information, it makes perfect sense. I pasted your PHP and Javascript snippets but it isn't working. I changed the POST variable name on results.php to $_POST['tweetID'] to match the data name in the Javascript but still no success. I've written a .done() command that creates an alert message, but have left it out until I can get the ajax working.

Comment: Neil posted a version of the script that works \o/ But I want to thank you for explaining this in a way that makes sense, and for your patience Thomas, I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: That's great.. Glad we could help steer in a clear & simple direction :)